# Flexible formula to match strings in 1 row to run a formula in matching columns in another row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I have a row where all strings have the identical format (XX-#####-##) in which Xs are 2 upper case alphabet letters and the #s are integers.

Short example, see the doc for more
KC-30000-00 | KC-30000-01 | KC-30000-02 | KC-30000-05 | KC-30000-99 | KC-33821-05

My plan is to run a formula (let's say add 10%) in the next row of all columns except for the columns with strings in the range of "KC-30000-00" to "KC-30000-98".

I tried to define the range using the formula below (and a few others) but it still includes -99 and I couldn't improve it
`=ArrayFormula(IF(COLUMN(A1:1)=1,"HEADER",REGEXMATCH(A1:1,"KC-30000-[0-9][0-9]$")))`

There are already many columns and it will grow so it's best to have a flexible formula in A3.

The doc has a few columns as a sample - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ytBameD5SrT6aNxed2sycKMB8BwMr8OVY5N1dO2vTjU/edit?usp=sharing

Please also feel free to suggest a better subject for this question to help others, perhaps.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your link permission is "View Only" without even the ability to make a copy or to copy and paste data; so there is no starting point for the volunteer contributors here. Please either open the sample sheet ("Anyone with the link" ... "Editor") or, at a minimum, remove the copy lock. Otherwise, as is already happening here, most volunteers will simply move on to the next post.

Comment: That was unintentional, I adjusted the sharing settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment to your post.

That said, eyeing it, this should work (in, say, A3 of an otherwise empty Row 3):

`=ArrayFormula({"Header", IF((B1:1="")+(REGEXMATCH(B1:1,"30000-[^(99)]")),,"do something")})`

The REGEXMATCH condition reads "30000 dash [anything that is `not` exactly the grouping `99`]."